# Post Migration Site Migration Redirects All Known Solutions Attempted

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I am running wp 6.1.1 wp 2023 theme with php8.1-fpm & apache2.

I am migrating a site from `webinar.example.test` to `staging.webinar.example.org`

I use git to push files and rsync/wp-cli to upload db and replace urls respectively.

This command `user@admin:~/public_html$ wp option get siteurl` CORRECTLY returns:

```
https://staging.webinar.example.org
```

When I enter the admin area for `staging.webinar.example.org`  and check `Settings --> General`  the Home and Site URL values are correct.

```
https://staging.webinar.example.org
```

When I enter the db using phpmyadmin and I examine the wp_options table and the home and siteurl are again correct.

**Problem:**
However, in multiple browsers on different machines... any time I access `staging.webinar.example.org` I am immediately redirected to `webinar.example.test`

What am I missing?

**More Info**

```
The `.htaccess` for `staging.webinar.example.org` contains:

root@admin:~/public_html$ cat .htaccess
# BEGIN iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line
# iThemes Security Config Details: 2
    # Enable HackRepair.com's blocklist feature - Security > Settings > Banned Users > Default Blocklist
    # Start HackRepair.com Blacklist
    RewriteEngine on
    # Start Abuse Agent Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*Indy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mozilla.*NEWT" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Maxthon$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SeaMonkey$" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Acunetix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^binlar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BlackWidow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bolt 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^BOT for JCE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Bot mailto\:craftbot@yahoo\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^casper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^checkprivacy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ChinaClaw" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^clshttp" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^cmsworldmap" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Custo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Default Browser 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^diavol" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DIIbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^DISCo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^dotbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Download Demon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^eCatch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EirGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailCollector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailSiphon" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EmailWolf" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Express WebPictures" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^extract" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ExtractorPro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^EyeNetIE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^feedfinder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FHscan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^FlashGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^flicky" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^g00g1e" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetRight" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GetWeb\!" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\!Zilla" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Go\-Ahead\-Got\-It" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^grab" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^GrabNet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Grafula" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^harvest" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^HMView" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Stripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Image Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InterGET" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Internet Ninja" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^InternetSeer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^jakarta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Java" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JetCar" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^JOC Web Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kanagawa" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^kmccrew" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^larbin" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^LeechFTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^libwww" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mass Downloader" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^microsoft\.url" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MIDown tool" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^miner" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Mister PiX" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^MSFrontPage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Navroad" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NearSite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Net Vampire" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetAnts" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^NetZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^nutch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Octopus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Explorer" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Offline Navigator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PageGrabber" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Papa Foto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pavuk" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pcBrowser" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^PeoplePal" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^planetwork" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^psbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^purebot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^pycurl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^RealDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^ReGet" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Rippers 0" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sitecheck\.internetseer\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SiteSnagger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^skygrid" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SmartDownload" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^SuperHTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Surfbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^tAkeOut" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Teleport Pro" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Toata dragostea mea pentru diavola" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^turnit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^vikspider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^VoidEYE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Web Image Collector" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebAuto" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebBandit" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebCopier" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebFetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebGo IS" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebLeacher" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebReaper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebSauger" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website eXtractor" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Website Quester" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebStripper" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebWhacker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WebZIP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Widow" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WPScan" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWW\-Mechanize" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^WWWOFFLE" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Xaldon WebSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^Zeus" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "^zmeu" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "360Spider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "CazoodleBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "discobot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "EasouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ecxi" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "GT\:\:WWW" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "heritrix" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTP\:\:Lite" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "HTTrack" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ia_archiver" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "id\-search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IDBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Indy Library" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "IRLbot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ISC Systems iRc Search 2\.1" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksCrawler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "LinksManager\.com_bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "linkwalker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "lwp\-trivial" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MFC_Tear_Sample" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Microsoft URL Control" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Missigua Locator" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "MJ12bot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panscient\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PECL\:\:HTTP" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PHPCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "PleaseCrawl" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SBIder" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "SearchmetricsBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Snoopy" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Steeler" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "URI\:\:Fetch" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "urllib" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Web Sucker" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "webalta" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WebCollage" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Wells Search II" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "WEP Search" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "XoviBot" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "YisouSpider" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "zermelo" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ZyBorg" [NC,OR]
    # End Abuse Agent Blocking
    # Start Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?semalt\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?kambasoft\.com" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} "^https?://(?:[^/]+\.)?savetubevideo\.com" [NC]
    # End Abuse HTTP Referrer Blocking
    RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
    # End HackRepair.com Blacklist, http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair

    # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
    <files .htaccess>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.html>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files readme.txt>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
    <files wp-config.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>

    # Disable Directory Browsing - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > Directory Browsing
    Options -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Protect System Files - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > System Files
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/install\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
        RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
        RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
        RewriteRule (^|.*/)\.(git|svn)/.* - [F]

        # Disable PHP in Uploads - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Uploads
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/uploads/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]

        # Disable PHP in Plugins - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Plugins
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/plugins/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]

        # Disable PHP in Themes - Security > Settings > System Tweaks > PHP in Themes
        RewriteRule ^wp\-content/themes/.*\.(?:php[1-7]?|pht|phtml?|phps)\.?$ - [NC,F]
    </IfModule>

    # Disable XML-RPC - Security > Settings > WordPress Tweaks > XML-RPC
    <files xmlrpc.php>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
            Require all denied
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </IfModule>
    </files>
# END iThemes Security - Do not modify or remove this line

# BEGIN LSCACHE
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
# END NON_LSCACHE
```

Comment: What's in your `.htaccess` file? [Edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/411817/edit) to include the relevant section.

Comment: @PatJ  contents added.

Comment: Did you try `wp search-replace webinar.example.test staging.webinar.example.org`?

Comment: @rudtek  I did... found nothing...  I finally got it working... (I really don't know how.) But now wp-cli throws "connection refused" errors, although it completes all commands successfully.. but that problem will have to be resolved on a different day.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the `wp-config.php` file and make sure it's not being set by the `WP_HOME` and/or the `WP_SITEURL` constants?

If you set the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in the `wp-config.php` file to `webinar.example.test`, but have the `home` and `siteurl` options in the `wp_options` table set to `staging.webinar.example.org`, then running the `wp option get siteurl` command would return the value of the `siteurl` option in the `wp_options` table, which is `staging.webinar.example.org`.

The `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants in `wp-config.php` are used to override the `home` and `siteurl` options in the `wp_options` table. However, if the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants are not set or are set to the same values as the `home` and `siteurl` options in the `wp_options` table, then the `wp option get siteurl` command will return the value of the `siteurl` option in the `wp_options` table.

If that doesn't solve the problem, then there are a few possible reasons why your WordPress site is being redirected to webinar.example.test even though the siteurl and home values in the database are correct.

Here are some possible causes and solutions:

- If you are using a caching plugin, it may be caching the old URL and
  redirecting to it. Try clearing the cache and see if that fixes the
  issue.
- If you are using a CDN, it may be caching the old URL and redirecting
  to it. Try clearing the CDN cache and see if that fixes the issue.
- If you have any custom code that is modifying the site URL, it may be
  using the old URL and redirecting to it. Check your custom code and
  see if you can find any references to the old URL.
- If you have any custom DNS records that are redirecting to the old
  URL, it may be causing the redirect. Check your DNS records and see
  if you can find any references to the old URL.

If none of these solutions fix the issue, you may need to further investigate the cause of the redirect. You can try using the `wp_redirect_status` filter hook to see which URL the site is being redirected to.

Here is an example:

```
function custom_redirect_status($status, $location, $code) {
    error_log("Redirect: $location ($code)");
    return $status;
}
```

This code logs the redirect URL and status code to the error log. You can then check the error log to see which URL the site is being redirected to. This can help you identify the cause of the redirect and find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up... I already resolved by adding the HOME and SITEURL constants to wp-config.php, plus doing something random that I can't exactly pinpoint... but everything seems to be working now.